# Apache Server Downloads .php Files in Subdirectories

Tags: php, html, apache

So I've been searching all over the internet for a solution to my problem and I've tried just about everything I could find, but still nothing is working.

My problem is that when I open a .php file in chromium by using:

```
localhost/filename.php
```

it works fine.  If I put the file in a subdirectory and access it as such:

```
localhost/subdirectory/filename.php
```

it works fine as well.  The problem comes when I try to access the .php file in the subdirectory from another file.  For example I have an entire project located under:

```
var/www/test
```

with the index.html sitting in that folder and then the .php scripts in a folder located at:

```
var/www/test/php_scripts
```

In the HMTL file there is a form that sends the form data to one of said .php scripts and when I click the submit button it downloads the .php script instead of navigating to it and executing in the browser.

I tried moving the script into the "test" folder so it was with the index.html file and that didn't fix anything.  If I place everything in:

```
var/www
```

it all works fine.  But I don't want to do that because then I have to deal with a cluttered mess of files which no one likes doing...

I did search for the past couple hours all over stack exchange and other sites and couldn't find anything that worked.  If this is a duplicate question then please point me in the direction of the answer, if not, hopefully one of you jedi coders can solve my headache.

Thanks,

Zak

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to look at the action part of your html form.

Make sure that the action starts with a /

Example

```
<form action="/php_scripts/script_name.php>
```

Comment: That did it! I thought I tried that before but I guess I didn't.  Its funny how the simple and easy things can throw off everything